Need help rendering a Viewcube in Unity UI Canvas Panel
I am new to Unity and not very familiar with its capabilities as of yet.  I am trying to create a viewcube like autocad in a scene. I have the viewcube functioning properly when it is added to a gameobject. I am trying to dock it in the corner and that is where my problems are. I have tried a couple different ways to do this but none of them is actually rendering the viewcube in the panel.  I can see the panel at runtime, but no viewcube. I am not sure what I am missing at this point.  Below you will find 2 functions.  SetViewCubeUI() and SetViewCubeUI2(), those are my two attempts to get it functional.
Here's my code
public class ViewCubeUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ViewCubePrefab;
    private Camera viewCubeCamera;
    private RenderTexture renderTexture;

    private void Start()
    {
        SetViewCubeUI();
        //SetViewCubeUI2();
    }

    private void SetViewCubeUI2()
    {
        // Create the RenderTexture
        renderTexture = new RenderTexture(256, 256, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);

        // Create a new GameObject for the camera
        GameObject cameraGameObject = new GameObject("ViewCubeCamera");
        viewCubeCamera = cameraGameObject.AddComponent<Camera>();
        viewCubeCamera.targetTexture = renderTexture;
        viewCubeCamera.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.SolidColor;
        viewCubeCamera.backgroundColor = Color.clear;
        viewCubeCamera.orthographic = true;
        viewCubeCamera.orthographicSize = 1;

        // Create the ViewCube GameObject
        GameObject viewCube = Instantiate(ViewCubePrefab, cameraGameObject.transform);
        viewCube.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

        // Create the UI elements
        GameObject canvasGO = new GameObject("ViewCubeCanvas");
        Canvas canvas = canvasGO.AddComponent<Canvas>();
        canvas.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;
        canvasGO.AddComponent<CanvasScaler>();
        canvasGO.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();

        // Create the panel
        GameObject panelGO = new GameObject("ViewCubePanel");
        RectTransform panelRect = panelGO.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        panelRect.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        panelRect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(400, 400);
        panelRect.anchorMin = new Vector2(1, 1);
        panelRect.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
        panelRect.pivot = new Vector2(1, 1);
        panelRect.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(-10, -10);

        // Add background image
        Image panelImage = panelGO.AddComponent<Image>();
        panelImage.color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.5f);

        // Create the RawImage to display the RenderTexture
        GameObject rawImageGO = new GameObject("ViewCubeImage");
        RectTransform rawImageRect = rawImageGO.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        rawImageRect.SetParent(panelRect, false);
        rawImageRect.sizeDelta = panelRect.sizeDelta;

        RawImage rawImage = rawImageGO.AddComponent<RawImage>();
        rawImage.texture = renderTexture;

        // Adjust camera position and rotation
        viewCubeCamera.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, -5);
        viewCubeCamera.transform.LookAt(viewCube.transform);
    }

    private void SetViewCubeUI()
    {
        renderTexture = new RenderTexture(256, 256, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);

        GameObject VCWidget = new GameObject("ViewCubeWidget");
        //make the canvas
        Canvas VCcanvas = VCWidget.AddComponent<Canvas>();
        VCcanvas.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;
        VCWidget.AddComponent<CanvasScaler>();
        VCWidget.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();

        //make the panel
        GameObject VCpanel = new GameObject("ViewCubePanel");
        RectTransform panelRect = VCpanel.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        panelRect.SetParent(VCcanvas.transform, false);
        panelRect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(600, 600);
        panelRect.anchorMin = new Vector2(1, 1);
        panelRect.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
        panelRect.pivot = new Vector2(1, 1);
        panelRect.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(-10, 10);

        //add background
        Image panelImage = VCpanel.AddComponent<Image>();
        panelImage.color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.5f);

        //Create the viewcube
        GameObject vc = new GameObject("ViewCube");
        vc.transform.SetParent(VCpanel.transform, false);            

        RectTransform vcRect = vc.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        vcRect.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        vcRect.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        vcRect.localScale = Vector3.one;
        vcRect.sizeDelta = panelRect.sizeDelta;

        vc.AddComponent<ViewCube.ViewCube>();

        
    }
}

In the screenshot below you can see the viewcube added to the scene inside a GameObject.  You can also see the grey overlay rectangle for my UI Panel that doesn't show anything.


ive no idea what a view cube is :P

For this exercise, imagine it is just a cube rendered in the panel that can spin around.  If you select a face of the cube it changes the camera angles

what happens when you look at the view cube in the scene view during play time.. im going to guess its far far away

if I utilize the viewcube script attached to a gameobject, without the UI, I can see it no problem.  I cannot get anything to show inside the UI Panel.  Its just a grey box.  I will attach an image to the original post

Image has been added

Is this UnityScript or C#?

Everything is written in C#

OK, so assuming the old UI.. you dont appear to be adding the UI elements to the canvas, they dont show without ..
